# why can't my variable display result value if its outside the function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from database and store the value into a variable, but it gives me undefined value which means variable is not storing the data.

```
  var n1;
  var reff=firebase.database().ref('login-demi/');
  reff.on("child_added", function(data){
    var newnum=data.val();
    n1=newnum.number; //4
    if (n1==4){
      n1=newnum.age;
    }
  });
  console.log(n1);
```

But if I try to "put console.log(n1)" inside the function under "n1=newnum.age;" then it will display the value, but i want the variable to store the value and display it outside the function can I know how can I do that?

Comment: variables have scope - determined by where (and in some ways how) they are declared - but all variables are unavailable outside of the function they are declared in - so `n1` inside that function definitely can't be accessed outside of that function - then there's the whole asynchrony thing which you haven't taken into consideration

Comment: you can fix the problem by removing `var` inside your function: `n1 = newnum.number`

Comment: @Kokodoko soory i already tried but it's still undefined

Comment: @JaromandaX so is there any way i can access it outside the function?

Comment: It's undefined because you `console.log()` it before firebase has returned the value.

Comment: So your problem is that you do not wait for the data to be loaded from firebase. You can fix that by putting `console.log()` inside the `reff.on()` handler too. Asynchronous data (as this is called) is mostly not available right away. The network takes time to send and receive the message.

Comment: no, you can't change the scope of a variable to suit your whims

Comment: oh, wait, you edited the code - yeah, now it's only the asynchrony that you don't understand that is the problem

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the function "reff.on" is an event function and what happens is that you print the n1 variable before the function is executed.

Therefore, you will only be able to access this data from within the function, Or you will build a specific function to verify that the previous function has been executed before you print the n1.

Notice how they only access the information from within the function in the Firebase documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference#parameters